# updating sql table for selected check box values

Tags: php, html, forms

I dynamically create table rows with checkboxes. Check a few of them and then perform and update query on the selected ones. But the problem I face is that only the first selected record gets updated even though I have used foreach loop.
Following is the code.

```
<?php
$checkbox = $_POST['pr'];
$year = $_POST['promoteyearselect1'];
$semester = $_POST['promotesemselect1'];


                          @ $db = mysql_connect("abc", "abc", "");
                            mysql_select_db("abc");



foreach($checkbox as $value){

        if(isset($checkbox)){



                            if(($semester%2)==0) {
                            $strSQL = "UPDATE student SET year='".++$year."', semester='".++$semester."' WHERE enrollment='".$value."'";
                            $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
                                if($rs){
                                echo 'Promotion Successful';
                                header("location:page1.php");
                                echo '<script> alert("Promotion Successful");</script>';

                                }   
                                else echo "Sorry, but that did not work. ";
                            }
                            else{
                            $strSQL = "UPDATE student SET semester=".++$semester."' WHERE enrollment='".$value."'";
                            $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
                                if($rs){
                                echo 'Promotion Successful';
                                header("location:page1.php");
                                echo '<script> alert("Promotion Successful");</script>';
                                }   
                                else echo "Sorry, but that did not work. ";
                            }
        }
}

mysql_close($db);               

?>
```

Even though I use the foreach loop to get through the array of checkboxes, still only the first checked record gets updated.

This is the html part

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-dark">
                            <select name="promoteyearselect1" id="promoteyearselect1" class="dropdown-select"  onfocus="showhidephdmenu()" form="promotionform" required>
                                <option value="">Select an option</option>
                                    <div id="yearselect1">
                                        <option value="1">1st</option>
                                        <option value="2">2nd</option>
                                        <option value="3">3rd</option>
                                        <option value="4">4th</option>
                                        <option value="5">5th</option>
                                    </div>  
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div> 


                        <div class="dropdown dropdown-dark">
                            <select name="promotesemselect1" id="promotesemselect1" class="dropdown-select" form="promotionform" required>
                                <option value="">Select an option</option>
                                <option value="1">1st</option>
                                <option value="2">2nd</option>
                                <option value="3">3rd</option>
                                <option value="4">4th</option>
                                <option value="5">5th</option>
                                <option value="6">6th</option>
                                <option value="7">7th</option>
                                <option value="8">8th</option>
                                <option value="9">9th</option>
                                <option value="10">10th</option>


                            </select>
                        </div> 
                        <button id="promotego" class="login-button" style=" position:relative; padding: 0 0 0; "  onclick="getpromotestudents()"></button>
            </div>
            <form id="promotionform" action="promotestudents.php" method="POST">

                <div id="promoteresults">
                    The results will show up here..!!
                </div>


                <div style=" position:relative; margin-top:10px; padding-left:44%;">  
                    <input type="submit" value="Promoted" class="button black"></input>
                    <a href="#" class="button black">Passed Out</a>
                </div>

            </form>
```

This is the PHP that gets the records and generates checkboxes.

```
$i=1;
                            while($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td class='promotetabledata'>".$r[7]."</td>";
                            echo "<td class='promotetabledata'>".$r[6]."</td>";
                            echo "<td class='promotetabledata'><input type='checkbox' name='pr[]'  value='".$r[7]."'/></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            $i++;
                }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: In php code you are using a variable with name 'pr', but I see no checkboxes with this this name in the HTML snippet. Please, show them.

Comment: @user4035 added the PHP code at the end that generates the checkboxes with name 'pr'

Comment: @DaveChen i switched to mysqli API, still only the first record is updated, not the rest. :/

Comment: @AkashGupta put var_dump($checkbox); before foreach and show me the result. I don't see any crucial errors in your code. Only move if(isset($checkbox)) out of forach and put it before foreach. No need to check, that the array is defined all the time.

Comment: the problem lies here..

`if(($semester%2)==0)`

I have tried it with spaces as well

`if(($semester % 2) == 0)`
I have tried it without brackets as well

`if($semester % 2 == 0)`

If i comment this line, the code works and for multiple selected records, else it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified code that finally worked for me, I added spaces in the `if($semester % 2 != 0)`

```
   <?php
    $checkbox = $_POST['pr'];
    $year = $_POST['promoteyearselect1'] + 1 ;
    $semester = $_POST['promotesemselect1'] + 1;

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","university") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));





    foreach($checkbox as $value){

            if(isset($checkbox)){
        //   echo $value;


                            if( $semester % 2 != 0) { 
                            //   echo $value;
                                $strSQL = "UPDATE student SET year='".$year."', semester='".$semester."' WHERE enrollment='".$value."'";
                                $rs = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);
                                    if($rs){
                                    echo 'Promotion Successful';
                                    header("location:page1.php");
                                    echo '<script> alert("Promotion Successful");</script>';

                                    }   
                                    else echo "Sorry, but that did not work. ";
                                }
                                else{
                                    $strSQL = "UPDATE student SET semester='".$semester."' WHERE enrollment='".$value."'";
                                    $rs = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);
                                    if($rs){
                                    echo 'Promotion Successful';
                                    header("location:page1.php");
                                    echo '<script> alert("Promotion Successful");</script>';
                                    }   
                                    else echo "Sorry, but that did not work. ";
                                }
            }
        }


    mysqli_close($con);             

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any checkbox with name 'pr' in your code..If there is any ..please make it an array and try 
like `<input type="checkbox" name="pr[]">`